# Tensorflow back_prop ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, tensorflow

I'm getting this value error:ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence, when doing back_prop in tensorflow. I'm using large [IMDB](http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/) dataset and [glove](http://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) 50d pre-trained vectors. I have tried everything converting multi-dimensional list into np.array, converting individual lists into np.array and also did reshape operation `x = x.reshape((batch,time_steps,embedding))`
on x but it gave me value error ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged. I think something is wrong with my input but don't know what? You could run this code on your pc by downloading IMDB dataset and 50d glove vectors. Please Help!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlp.py", line 109, in <module>
    sess.run(minimize_loss,feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 619, in _run
    np_val = np.array(subfeed_val, dtype=subfeed_dtype)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.



from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import os
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
batch = 500
start = 0
end = batch - 1
learning_rate = 0.2
num_classes = 8
path = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/train/pos"
time_steps = 250
embedding = 50

def get_embedding():
    gfile_path = os.path.join("/home/indy/Downloads/glove.6B", "glove.6B.50d.txt")
    f = open(gfile_path,'r')
    embeddings = {}
    for line in f:
        sp_value = line.split()
        word = sp_value[0]
        embedding = [float(value) for value in sp_value[1:]]
        embeddings[word] = embedding
    return embeddings

ebd = get_embedding()

def get_y(file_name):
    y_value = file_name.split('_')
    y_value = y_value[1].split('.')
    return y_value[0] 

def get_x(path,file_name):
    file_path = os.path.join(path,file_name)
    x_value = open(file_path,'r')
    for line in x_value:
        x_value = line.replace("<br /><br />","") 
        x_value = x_value.lower()
    tokeniz = TweetTokenizer()
    x_value = tokeniz.tokenize(x_value)
    padding = 250 - len(x_value)
    if padding > 0:
       p_value = ['pad' for i in range(padding)]
       x_value = np.concatenate((x_value,p_value))
    x_value = [ebd['value'] for value in x_value]

    return x_value

def  batch_f(path):
     directory = os.listdir(path)
     y = [get_y(directory[i]) for i in range(len(directory))]
     x = [get_x(path,directory[i]) for i in range(len(directory))]    
     return x,y


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch,time_steps,embedding])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch])

def build_nlp_model(x, _units, lstm_layers,num_classes):

     x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
     x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, embedding])
     x = tf.split(0, time_steps, x)


     lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = _units, state_is_tuple = True)

     multi_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * lstm_layers, state_is_tuple = True)

     outputs , state = tf.nn.rnn(multi_lstm,x, dtype = tf.float32)     

     weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([_units,num_classes]))
     biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

     logits = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases
     return logits

logits = build_nlp_model(X,400,4,num_classes)
c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(c_loss)



decayed_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate,0,10000,0.9)
optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer(decayed_learning_rate)
minimize_loss = optimizer.minimize(loss)



correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for i in range(25):
         x, y = batch_f(path)
         sess.run(minimize_loss,feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
         accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
         cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict = {X: x,Y: y})
         start = end 
         end = (start + batch)
         print ("Minibatch Loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(cost) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(accu))
```

EDIT: The other error that I'm getting, when I run the code.

```
(500, 250, 50)
(500,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlp.py", line 115, in <module>
    accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: targets[0] is out of range
     [[Node: InTopK = InTopK[T=DT_INT32, k=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add, _recv_Placeholder_1_0)]]
Caused by op u'InTopK', defined at:
  File "nlp.py", line 102, in <module>
    correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 890, in in_top_k
    targets=targets, k=k, name=name)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Comment: Can you please share the entire stack trace for the error you're seeing? That will help to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @mrry I have added the complete error!

Comment: The problem seems to be with the values returned by `batch_f()`. Internally TensorFlow will convert them to NumPy arrays, and the conversion is failing, usually because it isn't a dense array (e.g. it's a list of lists and the nested lists don't all have the same length). Another possibility is a type mismatch. Can you check that?

Comment: @mrry Output of batch_f() is a list of lists like a 3 dimensional list like(batch_size,time_steps,embedding).

Comment: Can you print the lengths of those nested lists, to ensure that they're uniform? One possibility is that some of the string-splits or tokenizations don't produce lists of the same length, leading to a ragged array (which can't be represented directly as a NumPy array).

Comment: @mrry Yes, they are uniform. len(batch_size) = 500 , len(time_steps) = 250 len(embedding) = 50

Comment: What do you get if you call `x, y = batch_f(path); print(np.array(x).shape); print(np.array(y).shape)`?

Comment: @mrry I ran the code and it gave me (12500, ) for x and (12500, ) for y. 12500 represents the number of files in the directory that has x and y values.

Comment: TensorFlow is expecting a `(500, 250, 50)` array for `x` and a `500`-element 1-D array for `y`. This points to a bug in `batch_f()`. My guess is that 1) you need to return slices of the data for each batch (size 500 in the 0th dimension), and 2) you need to check that the tokenizer is giving you 250 tokens for each row of `x` (or that you add sufficient padding).

Comment: @mrry Thanks I'm working on the problem. If there are other problems I'll let you know. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mrry I need your help! This line is giving me  ` x = [get_x(path,directory[i]) for i in range(len(directory))]  ` one-D array even though I'm inputting the data which is 2 dimensional(250,50) I don't where the problem is? I want this line to output 3 dimensional list from 2-D input data(250,50). get_x function is outputting 2-D input data(250,50)

Comment: This suggests that `get_x()` is returning lists of different sizes. When you try to pack them into a NumPy array, it creates a 1-D array of type `np.object` rather than a 3-D array of floats. I'd suggest adding two assertions to catch the problem: `assert len(embedding) == 50` in the `for` loop in `get_embedding()`, and `assert len(x_value) == 250` before the `return` statement in `get_x()`.

Comment: @mrry Everything else is working perfectly, but I'm getting an other error that is caused by 'InTopK'. I have edited my question and have added the error trace that I'm getting when I run the code. Could you please look into that?

Comment: @mrry I have figured out what was causing this error, it was due to mismatch between labels and outputs, like I'm doing 8 class sentiment classification and my labels are (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10) so it was unable to match predictions(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) with my labels, so that's why it was giving out of range error. But I have one last question, why it didn't gave me error in this line c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y) , how it's matching labels with predictions in this case as opposed to in in_top_k? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @mrry Could you please look into this issue? I think it should give me error when I'm using cross_entropy, because there is mismatch between predictions and labels.

Comment: Since the topic has drifted from the original question, can you please submit another self-contained question about the new issue, and I'll look at that?

Comment: @mrry Okay. I've posted it here. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38881918/tensorflow-tf-nn-in-top-k-targets-out-of-range-error

Comment: @mrry Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @mrry I think it's an issue, so I opened it on Github - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3739

Comment: @mrry It's an issue. - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a10e469d70827ede21c0bb5d0a46aac97404d4c/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L537