# Tensorflow tf.nn.in_top_k: targets out of range error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, cross-entropy

I have figured out what was causing this error, it was due to mismatch between labels and outputs, like I'm doing 8 class sentiment classification and my labels are (1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10) so it was unable to match predictions(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8) with my labels, so that's why it was giving out of range error. My question is, why it didn't gave me error in this line `c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)` , how it's matching labels with predictions in this case as opposed to in in_top_k? I think `c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)` should give me error because predictions and labels are not same. Why I'm not getting targets out of range error in cross entropy function?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math
import os
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
batch = 500
start = 0
end = batch - 1
learning_rate = 0.2
num_classes = 8
path = "/home/indy/Downloads/aclImdb/train/pos"
time_steps = 250
embedding = 50

def get_embedding():
    gfile_path = os.path.join("/home/indy/Downloads/glove.6B", "glove.6B.50d.txt")
    f = open(gfile_path,'r')
    embeddings = {}
    for line in f:
        sp_value = line.split()
        word = sp_value[0]
        embedding = [float(value) for value in sp_value[1:]]
        embeddings[word] = embedding
    return embeddings

ebd = get_embedding()

def get_y(file_name):
    y_value = file_name.split('_')
    y_value = y_value[1].split('.')
    return y_value[0] 

def get_x(path,file_name):
    file_path = os.path.join(path,file_name)
    x_value = open(file_path,'r')
    for line in x_value:
        x_value = line.replace("<br /><br />","") 
        x_value = x_value.lower()
    tokeniz = TweetTokenizer()
    x_value = tokeniz.tokenize(x_value)
    padding = 250 - len(x_value)
    if padding > 0:
       p_value = ['pad' for i in range(padding)]
       x_value = np.concatenate((x_value,p_value))
    x_value = [ebd['value'] for value in x_value]

    return x_value

def  batch_f(path):
     directory = os.listdir(path)
     y = [get_y(directory[i]) for i in range(len(directory))]
     x = [get_x(path,directory[i]) for i in range(len(directory))]    
     return x,y


X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch,time_steps,embedding])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batch])

def build_nlp_model(x, _units, lstm_layers,num_classes):

     x = tf.transpose(x, [1, 0, 2])
     x = tf.reshape(x, [-1, embedding])
     x = tf.split(0, time_steps, x)


     lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = _units, state_is_tuple = True)

     multi_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm] * lstm_layers, state_is_tuple = True)

     outputs , state = tf.nn.rnn(multi_lstm,x, dtype = tf.float32)     

     weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([_units,num_classes]))
     biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([num_classes]))

     logits = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights) + biases
     return logits

logits = build_nlp_model(X,400,4,num_classes)
c_loss = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,Y)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(c_loss)



decayed_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(learning_rate,0,10000,0.9)
optimizer= tf.train.AdamOptimizer(decayed_learning_rate)
minimize_loss = optimizer.minimize(loss)



correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predict, tf.float32))


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as sess:
     sess.run(init)
     for i in range(25):
         x, y = batch_f(path)
         sess.run(minimize_loss,feed_dict={X : x, Y : y})
         accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
         cost = sess.run(loss,feed_dict = {X: x,Y: y})
         start = end 
         end = (start + batch)
         print ("Minibatch Loss = " + "{:.6f}".format(cost) + ", Training Accuracy= " + "{:.5f}".format(accu))
```

This is the error stack.

```
(500, 250, 50)
(500,)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nlp.py", line 115, in <module>
    accu = sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict = {X: x, Y: y})
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 372, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 636, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 708, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 728, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: targets[0] is out of range
     [[Node: InTopK = InTopK[T=DT_INT32, k=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](add, _recv_Placeholder_1_0)]]
Caused by op u'InTopK', defined at:
  File "nlp.py", line 102, in <module>
    correct_predict = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, Y, 1)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py", line 890, in in_top_k
    targets=targets, k=k, name=name)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 704, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2260, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/indy/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1230, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

Comment: I think it's an issue, so I opened it on Github - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3739

Comment: It's an issue. - https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/2a10e469d70827ede21c0bb5d0a46aac97404d4c/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py#L537